# dzen2 how to detect actual resolution and number of monitors

Tags: xrandr, xmonad

I use `dzen2` with `xmonad` like this on my laptop:

```
 h <- spawnPipe "dzen2 -fn fixed -x 0 -y 800 -h 21 -w 1280 -ta l -fg '#ffffff' -bg '#663300' -e ''"
```

However there are some problems with it.

- If I use an external monitor alone with an other resolution it doesn't stay on the bottom of the screen (I guess since I set `-y 800`). However it should detect this automatically and position on the bottom of the screen.
- Same with width (for example when using a beamer). However it should set automatically the maximum width.
- If I use multiple monitors it is only on one monitor, but it would be great to have copies of it on each monitor.

How can I fix those issues?

Answer (score 0):

I run `xrandr`'s output through `awk` for something like this. E.g. this will get you the height of the tallest connected screen:

```
TALLEST_HEIGHT=`xrandr --prop --nograb | awk -F " |x+" 'BEGIN { max = 0 } / connected/ { if($5 > max){ max = $5 }}; END { print max }'`
```

You can then use this when calling `dzen`:

```
dzen -h $TALLEST_HEIGHT (...)
```

Similar logic can be applied to many cases, if you switch `$5` with `$4` you'll get the width, and it also can be easily adapted to get the smallest screen instead of the widest.  You can also take a look at fields `$6` and `$7` which will tell you the offset of each display, and use them to get to the very bottom (or very left) of the picture.